# How do I find out what my external IP address is?

Tags: windows, networking

My computers are sitting behind a router/firewall. How do I programmatically find out what my external IP address is. I can use http://www.whatsmyip.org/ for ad-hoc queries, but the TOS don't allow for automated checks.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for respecting the TOS!

Comment: If you don't own the server you're working on, you'll want to make sure you have access to hosts outside the network before putting any real effort into the project.

Comment: You can't, because in general a computer could have *several* IP (or *none*, if your HTTP requests go thru a proxy)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

http://ipecho.net/plain appears to be a
   workable alternative, as whatismyip.com now requires membership for
   their automated link.  They very kindly appear to be
   [offering](http://ipecho.net/developers.html) this service for free,
   so please don't abuse it.

Comment: For more info about why this is the preferred way:

http://www.whatismyip.com/automation

Comment: whatismyip now charge for this service. You can find out more at http://www.whatismyip.com/membership-options/

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do it.

I would use a site like [www.whatsmyip.org](http://www.whatsmyip.org/) and parse the output.

[checkip.dyndns.com](http://checkip.dyndns.com/) returns a very simple HTML file which looks like this:

> ```
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <title>Current IP Check</title>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     Current IP Address: 84.151.156.163
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

This should be very easy to parse.
Moreover the site is exists for about ten years. 
There is hope that it will be around for a while.

Comment: Unfortunately, the DynDns service is to be used only when you are using their services (http://dyn.com/support/developers/checkip-tool/).

Comment: I do use this. It's very easy to parse in most languages- in Python it is a single line of code to remove all the extra lines of code (filebuffer[before:-after] where before and after are the number of characters before and after, and are constants.) @IvanMesic, you don't have to use any of their services to use this site.

Answer (score 11):

If you have access to a webserver with modphp, you can roll your own:

```
<?php print $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>
```

If you don't want that to get abused, you'll have to keep it secret or add request limits.

I've been using one on my server for years.

Explicitly:

Create a file called whatismyip.php in your public_html folder in your website. It can be called anything and be anywhere in your webroot.

Add the line above, and then query your server:

```
curl http://example.com/whatismyip.php
```

for example.

Comment: I added a script like this to my server years ago and it is very useful. Everything else is bizarre overkill.

Comment: but we're lazy, that's why we're looking for something quick on SO!

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately as of 2013, whatismyip.com charge for the service.

http://www.icanhazip.com is still going strong, 3 years later. Just outputs the IP as text, absolutely nothing else.

http://checkip.dyndns.org still works as well.

You can also use Google if you want to be sure it won't go down, but it can still block you for TOS violations.

https://www.google.ie/search?q=whats+is+my+ip

But even when they block me, they still tell me my client IP address in the error message.

Answer (score 4):

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

or

```
curl ifconfig.me/ip
```

Incase you don't have curl installed,

```
wget ifconfig.me/ip 2>/dev/null && cat ip
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If the router you are behind speak UPnP you could always use a UPnP library for whatever language you are developing in to query the router for its external ip.

Answer (score 2):

http://myexternalip.com provides this kind of information. To 
retrieve your IP you have plenty of options:

- http://myexternalip.com/ - browser + lot's of examples of how to use it
- http://myexternalip.com/raw - a pure text answer, only your ip, no other crap
- http://myexternalip.com/json - a resposnse ready for json-parsers, also supports jsonp
- HEAD http://myexternalip.com - send only a HEAD-request and get the answer

Answer (score 2):

Since this question was asked a while back, there's now a freely available web service designed specifically to allow you to determine your IP address programmatically, called [ipify](https://www.ipify.org/).

```
$ curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json'
```

Results in

```
{"ip": "1.2.3.4" /* your public IP */}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is if you have access to a cloud email (yahoo, google, hotmail), send yourself an email. Then view the headers and you should see your IP address in there.

I would look up the exact area but the headers may vary from each implmentation, Look for the received-by and follow that until you get to something that looks like sent-by

EDIT: This answers the how to find IP address, not the via PROGRAMMATIC approach

Comment: That's an extremely inefficient idea.

Comment: Maybe inefficient but if you are on a locked down workstation and cannot get to the external device its another method you may use.

Answer (score 1):

My WRT54G router tells me through its Local Router Access feature (the http(s) administration interface), and I imagine something similar could be done with many other devices. In this case, the entry page gives the octets of the IPv4 address in four lines containing this phrase:

class=num maxLength=3 size=3 value='**i**' name='wan_ipaddr_**N**' id='wan_ipaddr_**N**'

Where **i** is the octet value and **N** is the octet number. This bit of doggerel fetches and parses it for me, courtesy of cygwin:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my( $account, $password ) = @ARGV;

open QUERY,
    "curl --sslv3 --user '$account:$password' https://Linksys/ --silent |"
    or die "Failed to connect to router";

my @ipaddr = ('x','x','x','x');

while( <QUERY> ) {
    $ipaddr[$2] = $1 if /value='(\d+)' name='wan_ipaddr_([0-3])/;
}
close QUERY;
print join('.', @ipaddr);
```

There is no guarantee that this will work with all versions of the router firmware.

If your router is set to use http for this interface, drop the --sslv3 curl option, and you can use dotted-decimal notation to address the router. To use https with the curl options above, I also did this:

1. Used a browser to fetch the router's self-signed certificate (saved as Linksys.crt).
2. Added it to my CA bundle:

   ```
   openssl x509 -in Linksys.crt -text >> /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
   ```
3. Added 'Linksys' to my hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\HOSTS on my Win8 box), as an alias for the router's address. If the dotted-decimal notation is given to curl instead of this alias, it rejects the connection on account of a certificate subject name mismatch.

Alternatively, you could just use the --insecure option to bypass certificate verification, which probably makes more sense in the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

whatismyip.com or ipchicken.com are very easy to parse.

If you have a webhost or vps you can also determine it, without fear of it randomly going down leaving you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

[ifcfg.me](http://ifcfg.me)
allows Lookup via

nslookup
telnet
ftp
and http

even works with IPv6

Answer (score -2):

Simple but not elegant for this use.  I created a VBS file with the following code to drop the result to dropbox and google drive ... have to delete the file for new one to sync though for some reason.

This runs on a PC at my home.  My PC is set to resume on power outage and a task is scheduled to run this every day once (note if you have it run often, the site will block your requests).

Now I can get my IP address on the road and watch people steal my stuff :-)

```
get_html "http://ipecho.net/plain", "C:\Users\joe\Google Drive\IP.html"

get_html "http://ipecho.net/plain", "C:\Users\joe\Dropbox\IP.html"



sub get_html (up_http, down_http)

dim xmlhttp : set xmlhttp = createobject("msxml2.xmlhttp.3.0")

xmlhttp.open "get", up_http, false

xmlhttp.send

dim fso : set fso = createobject ("scripting.filesystemobject")

dim newfile : set newfile = fso.createtextfile(down_http, true)

newfile.write (xmlhttp.responseText)

newfile.close

set newfile = nothing
set xmlhttp = nothing

end sub
```