# how to know my public ip address of pc

Tags: networking, window, ip, ip-address

I have connected to my router device through the Wi-Fi.

i have run 'ipconfig' in command prompt but its not showing public IP address to access system remotely.
[image: its showing these]
so how can I get public IP address of my personal computer.

I have tried using router id(find through the what is my IP org)

Comment: If your router is not properly setup to allow traffic from outside to pass to your PC, then there is no use in knowing the "public" IP of the router. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to access my PC remotely from other system

Comment: I think you answered your own question already: Go to http://www.whatsmyip.org/ and read the address there :-)

Comment: it showing my router ip only

Comment: Your router IP is your public IP. To access you computer from another system, you might also have to use port forwarding on your router. This question could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1145899/897968 ...which has an answer you might be interested in.

Comment: Also take a look at NAT (Network Address Translation)

Comment: simple get your public ip: `curl -Ss http://dadouqz.com/my|jq -r .client_ip`

Answer (score 14):

If you are behind a router, then your computer will not know about the public IP address as the router does a network address translation. You could ask some website what your public IP address is using curl or wget and extract the information you need from it:

```
curl -s checkip.dyndns.org | sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'
```

or shorter

```
curl ipinfo.io/ip
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a DNS request instead of HTTP request to find out your public IP:

```
C:\> nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com
```

It uses `resolver1.opendns.com` dns server to resolve the magical `myip.opendns.com` hostname to your ip address

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to access your PC remotely through a router, you need to enable the router for what is sometimes called "port forwarding" (some routers might call it differently).

To get the IP of the router you can either login to the router's config page (or if it has a config utility use it), or as you mentionned go to whatsmyip.org and you will see the external address of the router.

But again, if you don't setup the router accordingly, you will not be able to access your PC.

Cheers

EDIT: Your PC doesn't have an external IP. Only the router does. By setting up port forwarding, the router will take care of routing the external incoming traffic to your PC, but your PC will never be visible to the internet. Only the router.

Answer (score 0):

To find your public IP, try this link:

http://www.whatismyip.global/

This website even keeps a history of your IPs.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already answered but just in case someone want to check it in terminal:

`curl ipconf.cf`

Comment: Seems no longer valid.

Answer (score -1):

Simply try https://ipaddress.tech to find your public IP Address and location information. This is simple, easy and free service that i have developed.