# How to get system IP address using in scala code?

Tags: scala

I want to set the ipaddress in variable using scala. I have tried below scenario. I did not get exactly what I was looking for.

```
val sysip = System.InetAddress.getLocalHost();
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get public IP Address of the current machine using scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392549/get-public-ip-address-of-the-current-machine-using-scala)

Comment: Which IP are you trying to get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import java.net._

val localhost: InetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost
val localIpAddress: String = localhost.getHostAddress

println(s"localIpAddress = $localIpAddress")
```

You can find more details via this [link](http://www.scalafied.com/31/getting-ip-address-mac-address-and-subnet-mask-of-localhost)